# Locate strings.xml file in the project res folder [Eclipse]

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am a first time `Eclipse` user   and I am trying to create my first application on an `Android emulator`.

So I just finished downloading the `Android developer SDK` package and I created the "`My First App`" application using the `step-by-step` tutorials provided there.

I am now trying to learn how to be able to change the text and play around with the application.

My question is:
Which file do I code in to change the text/look of the application?

I looked this question up and it said to do the edits 
(such as deleting the "`Hello World`" string and putting in whatever you would like) by editing the string.xml file which should be found in the res folder.

I found my res folder in on the left but inside there is no "`string.xml`" file, I just have the android picture(of the robot), two text files, and the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Also, to edit and change things in the application for Android is it all done in `XML or Java`? I always thought it was done with Java but it seems that it is mainly `XML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can find string.xml in res->values folder path. But you can also open in second way like this.

- Open any of your activity's xml file.
- Below is an image of xml file
- > [image]
- Press <kbd>Ctrl Key</kbd> and move your mouse pointer to the text where it is indicating `@string/loginTitle` and click.
- This will open your string.xml file.

Comment: Where is the activity's xml file? Because I can't find the TextView tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file which is what I think is the activity's xml file.

Comment: Activity's file is under the res->layout folder

Comment: But I don't have a layout folder

Comment: How this can be possible ? can you show me a snapshot of your eclipse  ?

Comment: what do you mean by back track xml file ?

Comment: I found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Res -> values -> strings.xml

If you want to change the layout/look of your activity/application, go to Res -> Layout -> activity_main.xml (or whatever the name of your layout file is)

Comment: I don't have the values or layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

`res > values > strings.xml`

As for the XML vs Java thing, I'd say that dynamic layout changes are done using Java, but the base layouts are done using XML files. Start with XML, change during runtime with Java.

And your XML files for your layouts will be in `res > layout > activity_main.xml`

Comment: I don't have the values or layout folders.